# Can NIFI caculate the next business day from a Date?

Tags: regex, date, apache-nifi

I am working on a NIFI project which I want to get the next business day.

For example if I input Jan-14-2022, I can get next businessday is Jan-18-2022 since 14th, 15th is weekends and 17th is holiday.

I currently have

`:toDate('MMM-dd-yyyy'):toNumber():plus(86400000):format('MMM-dd-yyyy')`
which will add 24 hours and return me the date one day after.
But how Can I get the next business day?

Comment: business day depends on your company/state/country etc. it's not a valid request to nifi.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that a NiFi Processor could be configured to do using something such as a script or another option inside a processor.

However, this is something that would better be done with code, not NiFI as this isnt something that NiFi can natively do. I am not aware if this is something natively something NiFi should and can do.